# Can anyone tell me how to create PDF with text Annotate using libHaru Library

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf-generation, libharu

I wanted to create a PDF with a Text Annotate. I came across the 3rd Party library called libharu. Can anybody tell me how to create a PDF with a text annotate using this library or any documentation related to it.

Comment: did you find out how Annotations work with libHaru? The example code is not much of a help. I need to set the custom annotation background and icon etc but unable to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The libharu site has an [example of annotation in C](http://libharu.org/demo/text_annotation.c).